# 'git remote -v' delete unwanted repositories locally

Tags: git, git-bash, git-remote

when I type `git remote -v` in git bash I get a list of all the repository urls, the problem is they are all outdated I want to delete all of them. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove remotes by their names using `git remote remove`. E.g.:

```
$ git remote remove myremote
```

Answer (score 0):

Few options to remove remotes

- You can simply edit the `.git/config` file and remove them
- `git remote remove <remote>`
- `git remote rm <remote>`
- `git remote prune <remote>`

---

#### `git remote rm`

> **`rm`**
>   Remove the remote named .
>   All remote tracking branches and configuration settings for the remote are removed.

#### **`git remote prune`**

> **`prune`**
>   Deletes all stale tracking branches under . These stale branches have already been removed from the remote repository referenced by , but are still locally available in "remotes/".
>   With --dry-run option, report what branches will be pruned, but do not actually prune them.

Comment: It isn't a good idea to manually edit any of the files beneath the `.git` directory as long as there are good, documented, ways of performing the same operations using `git` commands.